# Excesso do uso de sessões pode parar uma pool no IIS?

Tags: session, iis-7

O excesso do uso de sessões pode causar a parada de uma pool?

Assumindo que seja estouro de memória, neste caso, resulta em exceções também contabilizadas nas configurações de proteção de falha da pool ou em parada imediata, ou reciclagem?

Existe um log do IIS que indique a parada efetiva da pool por qualquer motivo? Estouro de memória, exceções em excesso a configuração, etc?